# Maximum principle of a differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider  the boundary value problem $$g(x) - g’’(x) = f(x), \qquad x \in (0,1),$$
with boundary conditions $g(0)=g(1)=0$ and $f$ beeing a function in $C([0,1])$.

My question is, how can I show from the information above that $$||g||_{\infty}\le \frac{1}{7}||f||_{\infty},$$ and that this implies that there is an unique solution for $f\in C([0,1])$?

($||\cdot||_{\infty}$ denotes the $\infty$-norm)

I know there is a proposition that applies for the Poisson’s equation on the form $$-g’’(x) = f(x) \quad x \in (0,1) \quad g(0)=g(1)=0$$
That states that $||g||_{\infty}\le \frac{1}{8}||f||_{\infty}$. I did not however manage to apply this in order to solve the given equation. Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2):

We have $-g''(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, so applying your proposition with "$f(x)$" = $f(x) - g(x)$ gives

$$
\|g\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{8}\|f - g\| \le \frac{1}{8}\|f\|_\infty + \frac{1}{8}\|g\|_\infty,
$$

where we also use the triangle inequality. Rearranging gives $\|g\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty/7$.

Now suppose that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are two solutions, then $g_1-g_2$ solves the equation $(g_1-g_2)(x)-(g_1-g_2)''(x) = f(x) - f(x) = 0$, so using our inequality with "$f(x)$" $=0$ gives $\|g_1 - g_2\|_\infty \le \|0\|_\infty/7 = 0$. Thus $\|g_1 - g_2\|_\infty = 0$ so $g_1 = g_2$. Uniqueness is shown.

Comment: Thank you very much :)